# What is the regular expression to allow starting with uppercase, followed by lowercase letters?

Tags: c#, regex

I am having problems creating a regex validator that checks to make sure the input starts with a capital letter, followed by lowercase letters. It can also contain an apostrophe ('), and whitespace " ".

These are ok:

```
Red hot chili peppers 
Eminem
Guns n' roses
```

Invalid:

```
ReD Hot CiLly PePers
sLipKnot
guns n'roses
```

I'm trying to learn Regex, but it's hard for me... What I had done [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/38xP7p/1)

Comment: **E**minem and **Guns** ? Or is the rule more like: As many UPPERCASE words as possible followed by lowercase words?

Comment: @Jan, I'm sorry. My fault. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

`^[A-Z][a-z ']+$`

so in your sample Eminem, Guns n' roses is not ok

---

`^` matches start of line

`[A-Z]` matches 1 UpperCase Letter

`[a-z ']+` matches at less 1 (lowercase letter or space or ')  (`+` means 1 or more)

`$` matches the end of line

Comment: I'm sorry. My fault. I've fixed it

Comment: @Nikol Dimitrova, no problem!!

Comment: if it helps  please, dont forget to upvote/validate the answer!!